# Why this formulation is not the official exposition of ZF-?

Tags: set-theory, axioms, philosophy

**Specification:** if $\phi$ is a formula that doesn't use the symbol $x$, with symbols $``y,a,b"$ as its free variables, then : $$\forall a \forall b:  \forall k \exists! x \forall y (y \in x \leftrightarrow y \in k \land \phi) $$

**Reflection:** if $\phi$ is a formula with symbols $``a,b"$ as its free variables, that doesn't use the symbol $\mathsf  v$ ; and if $\phi^\mathsf v$ is the formula obtained by bounding all quantifiers in $\phi$ with $\mathsf v$, then: $$\forall a \forall b \ \exists \text{ supertrs } \mathsf v : \phi \implies \phi^\mathsf v$$

Where:

$\mathsf v \text{ is supertrs} \equiv_{df} \forall m \forall n (m \in v \land (n \in m \lor n \subseteq m) \to n \in v)$

That is: a supertransitive set is a set closed under $\in$ and $\subseteq$ relations.

This is a modification of Dana Scott's theory about sets and stages, and I believe this proves all axioms of ZF-Reg., and even without Extensionality it can interpret ZFC.

This exposition of ZF- is actually very simple, neat and elegant. It is much shorter than the usual presentation of ZF- by axioms of Extensionality, Empty, Set union, Power, Separation, Replacement, and Infinity. Moreover, it appears to be pretty much natural and reduces all those diversily looking axioms into just two simple principles "we reflect, then specify!", that's all.

> Since this is a well established result decades ago, then given the merits of shortage, elegance, and principled reduction; why it was not adopted as the official exposition of ZF-?

Comment: Isn't this more of a sociological question than a mathematical one?

Comment: I think this ought to be part of mathematics also. Who else other than mathematicians would discuss such an issue? The choice of axiomatics? Is there a clear "mathematical" base or lets say foundational conviction for preferring the ordinary presentation over that one. I'm not asking about sociological motivation. I'm asking about a justification for preferring exposition of axiomatics, which should matter!

Comment: I mean, just motivation is enough, I think. Extensionality, separation, pairing, power set, etc are easy-to-understand principles recognizable to any mathematician. Reflection and the cumulative hierarchy, not so much.

Comment: Sure, there are subtleties about replacement and foundation that aren't as widely understood, but even those can be picked up pretty quickly by a person who's interested but not that interested.

Comment: But reflection above is pretty much easy, any property that is true in the whole world would hold inside some supertransitive set, this is much simpler than a combination of power, union, infinity, and replacement, axioms which look quite heterogenous, while with reflection you have one rather simple and relatively clear principle. There are some subtilities with it, but not so much.

Comment: It looks like you value conciseness. Some of us value separation of concerns (i.e., what you disparage as heterogeneity). I spend a lot of my time working in systems without replacement. Does your proposal help me with that?

Comment: Anything is easy once you understand it. But even the idea of a transitive set is a little foreign outside set theory, not to mention this idea of 'properties which hold in the whole world should hold in some fragment'... why? Of course many of these criticisms could also be leveled against the standard presentation of ZFC, where after all these properties eventually emerge as important. Even basic stuff like 'why is everything a set' leads to criticism that ZFC doesn't capture how mathematicians think. But it helps that familiar things like pairs and power sets are there on the ground floor.

Comment: @RobArthan, its not about conciseness, much it about principal reduction. The point is that all of those heterogeneously presented principles can be reduced into a common principle that is not an artificial amalgamation of all of them (although you can accuse the "super" part as being deliberately made to interpret powers), the presentation is at the end simple and not cumbersome at all. So, I think this is a significant result that is ought to be mentioned at least beside the formal exposition of the axioms.

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen, you asked "'properties which hold in the whole world should hold in some fragment'... why?" I think because of maximality approaches related to coverage of properties within sets.

Comment: @Zuhair My “why?” was from the perspective of a person without much knowledge of set theory you are trying to motivate these axioms to. I’m imagining trying to teach this to a class of, say, advanced undergraduates who have recently learned 1st order logic and convince them this should be how sets behave. I imagine I would have a much easier time with the standard  axiomatization.

Comment: the same "why"? applies to taking *together* union, power, infinity, and replacement, you may succeed to motivate each axiom alone, but to motivate the whole combination is also not that easy. I know that understanding them is easy, although not very easy really for a beginner. But yet its not easy to motivate having all of them. The reflection principle is ONE principle that explains all of those, so using it is a more principled approach, and since its *equivalent* to the ordinary axioms, then any fundamental objection to it is also a fundamental objection to the ordinary exposition.

Comment: cont....; also I don't see it really that much difficult to understand and apply, everything is hard at the beginning (even the ordinary axioms), but once its mastered, it works well, that is besides the ordinary axioms will be involved in the primary application of it anyway, so they are still there, they need not be at the FLOOR level, they can be at the next level. Reflection is important for extending ZFC, and so learning it from the outset is a merit in that respect.

Comment: [*Frege meets Zermelo: a perspective on ineffability and reflection*](http://people.ucalgary.ca/~rzach/static/banff/rsl-specialissue/shapiro-uzquiano/shapiro-uzquiano.pdf) by Shapiro and Uzquiano says on page 6 that transitivity (as opposed to supertransitivity) is sufficient, which would simplify this even further to just $\forall x \exists y \forall z (z \in y \leftrightarrow z \in x \land \phi)$ where $y$ is not free in $\phi$ (specification) and $\phi \to \exists x (\mathrm{transitive}(x) \land \phi^x)$ where $x$ is not free in $\phi$ (reflection).

Comment: @user76284 I think they were speaking in second (or higher) order logic. Here this theory is first order, so I don't think what they are speaking applies here. However, I'll double check on that issue.

Comment: I think you're right. I posted a question about it [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4318271/does-separation-reflection-prove-zf-extensionality-foundation). Is the ! in your specification schema necessary?

Comment: @user76284, Yes! If you want Extensionality to be a theorem. However, if we remove it, we still have a theory that can *interpret* ZFC.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Leaving aside communal inertia ("why change a perfectly fine presentation?"), which is of course significant, I don't see the benefit of this proposed reaxiomatization.

---

> It is much shorter than the usual presentation of ZF- by axioms of Extensionality, Empty, Set union, Power, Separation, Replacement, and Infinity.

Sure, but length isn't an inherent indicator of quality.

> This exposition of ZF- is actually very simple

Is it? Someone new to the field would have substantially more difficulty using it, I suspect, than using the usual $\mathsf{ZF-}$ axioms. Simplicity *of presentation* and simplicity *of use* are two different things, and in most situations I think the latter is more important than the former.

> it appears to be pretty much natural and reduces all those diversily looking axioms into just two simple principles "we reflect, then specify!", that's all

Again, I don't really buy this: why should "we reflect, then specify" **be** an accepted bit of set-theoretic intuition? Motivating reflection is nontrivial. By contrast, the $\mathsf{ZF-}$ axioms are **graded**: consider the various levels of "justifiability" of e.g. Pairing, Infinity, Replacement, and Powerset. Someone who doesn't find all of them intuitive will still (probably) find some of them intuitive, and so a larger portion of the theory is "immediately acceptable." I think this is very useful for the *pragmatic* side of things: to a strong set theory skeptic we can argue that the "inoffensive part" of $\mathsf{ZF-}$ is still strong enough to do what they need, while it's not clear how to whip up something similar for your approach.

There's also the more technical aspect: if you're interested in *fragments of* $\mathsf{ZF-}$ (which I personally am very much), a more modular approach is significantly easier to use.

---

To sum up, I think that while this is of course a neat result, as an axiomatization of $\mathsf{ZF-}$ it is inferior to the standard one(s) in terms of intuitive appeal and immediate usability - and I don't think that its advantages make up for that.

Comment: I propose a new axiom UPIE, it's the conjunction of Union, Power Set, Infinity, and Extensionality (**in that order!**), now ZF- is *even shorter!*

Comment: Ok, I do agree that there is some lets say "ease of use" with the commonly presented axioms, but still I think this result which is I think due to Dana Scott or perhaps Montague is in some sense significant that it warrants mentioning it in the formal exposition at least as a concluding axiomatization that sums everything and actually *reduce* them to common just two principles. A result like that shouldn't be ignored, at least as an official alternative presentation of ZF-.

Comment: @AsafKaragila, No. What you are saying doesn't parallel this situation. I'm not speaking just of shortness. Here, there is a principle that all of those axioms you've mentioned together with replacement are traceable to, and this traceability is not so trivial, and on the other hand its not artificial. So, I see it's worth mentioning at least annexed with the common axiomatization.

Comment: I don't think the graded point is significant here, because this can be done with any system. Once you proved all of those statements, and you think the theory is consistent, then of course you may go and examine fragments, this objection can hold even of the common presentation of ZFC since there are fragments of it that are studied like bounded Zermelo for example that the exposition is not decomposed to.

Comment: Motivation is not addative, yes one can see a motivation for each axiom of pairing, union, infinity, replacement, and power, but the problem is in motivating having all of them together. That is not easy! The more the axioms are heterogenous the more difficult to motivate having them together. Reflection does have its motivation, it suites more Gigantic theories, and actually ZF- is Gigantic, so its essence lies in some kind of reflection principle. Launching arguments against reflection is equal to lauching arguments against ZF- itself.

Comment: in last comment, I meant raising fundamental objections and not expositional.

Comment: Reflection actually has deep roots in the history and philosophy of set theory. Gödel and (I believe) Cantor made comments along the lines that it should be considered *the* principle that motivates all the axioms of set theory.