# Does separation + reflection prove ZF - extensionality - foundation?

Tags: logic, set-theory, axioms, foundations, alternative-set-theories

Assume a [first-order](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-order_logic) context. Let $\mathrm{tran}(x)$ denote that $x$ is [transitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transitive_set):

$$\mathrm{tran}(x) \leftrightarrow (\forall y \in x) (\forall z \in y) (z \in x)$$

Let $\mathrm{suptran}(x)$ denote that $x$ is [supertransitive](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Supertransitive_class):

$$\mathrm{suptran}(x) \leftrightarrow (\forall y \in x) (\forall z \subseteq y) (z \in x)$$

Consider the following axiom schemas of [reflection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_principle):

\begin{align}
& \phi \to \exists x (\phi^x \land \mathrm{tran}(x)) & \text{R1} \\
& \phi \to \exists x (\phi^x \land \mathrm{tran}(x) \land \mathrm{suptran}(x)) & \text{R2}
\end{align}

where $\phi$ is any formula in which $x$ is not free and $\phi^x$ is the relativization of $\phi$ to $x$ (changing all quantifiers in $\phi$ to range over $x$). Ref. 1 says extensionality, separation, and R1 prove pairs, union, powerset, infinity, and replacement. Ref. 2 says

> Extensionality, Separation, and Foundation, together with the Reflection Principle, formulated as the axiom schema asserting that each formula is reflected by some set that contains all elements and all subsets of its elements (note that the V<sub>α</sub> are like this), is equivalent to ZF.

My questions are the following:

1. Is the supertransitivity condition, as opposed to just transitivity, necessary?
2. Does separation + R# (without extensionality) prove ZF - extensionality - foundation?

---

References:

1. Stewart Shapiro, Gabriel Uzquiano. *Frege meets zermelo: A perspective on ineffability and reflection: A perspective on ineffability and reflection*. Cambridge University Press: 2008-08-01. [http://people.ucalgary.ca/~rzach/static/banff/rsl-specialissue/shapiro-uzquiano/shapiro-uzquiano.pdf](http://people.ucalgary.ca/%7Erzach/static/banff/rsl-specialissue/shapiro-uzquiano/shapiro-uzquiano.pdf). Page 6.
2. Joan Bagaria. *Set Theory*. Stanford Encyclopedia of Philosophy: 2019-02-12. https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/set-theory/#UniVAllSet. Section 4, last paragraph.

Answer (score 1):

1. Supertransitivity (in other words, $V_\alpha$ for some limit $\alpha$) is necessary.

   Assume that $V=L$ and consider $L_{\omega_1}$. It is known that $L_{\omega_1}$ satisfies $\mathsf{ZFC}^-$, that is, $\mathsf{ZFC}$ without Power Set. Furthermore, $L_{\omega_1}$ also satisfies Reflection in a sense that for every formula $\phi(x)$ with a parameter $a$, we can find $\alpha<\omega_1$ such that $a\in L_\alpha$ and
   $$L_{\omega_1}\models \phi(a)\leftrightarrow \phi^{L_\alpha}(a).$$

   Especially, $L_{\omega_1}$ satisfies Extensionality, Separation, Foundation, and R1. However, it does not satisfy the full $\mathsf{ZF}$.
2. Everything becomes tricky if we do not have extensionality. However, the above result also shows that R1 + Separation does not prove $\mathsf{ZF}$ without Separation and Foundation. (If were, $L_{\omega_1}$ must satisfy Powerset.)

   I have no idea what happens if we assume R2. However, the following variant of R2 proves other axioms of ZF (except for Extensionality and Foundation):

   $$\forall a_1\cdots \forall a_n[ \exists x (a_1,\cdots,a_n\in x\land \text{$x$ is transitive and supertransitive}\land \forall t\in x \ [\phi_0(t)\leftrightarrow \phi^x_0(t)] \land\cdots\land [\phi_n(t)\leftrightarrow \phi^x_n(t)]   )]. $$

   The most tricky axiom would be Replacement: assume that $\forall x\in a\exists!y \phi(x,y)$. Find a supertransitive $M\ni a$ that reflects $\forall x\in a\exists!y \phi(x,y)$ and $\phi(x,y)$. Then consider the set $R$ given by

   $$y\in R \leftrightarrow y\in M \land \exists x\in a\  \phi(x,y).$$

Comment: According to Shapiro and Uzquiano, Extensionality, Separation, and R1 prove Pairing, Union, Powerset, Infinity, and Replacement. Since $L_{\omega_1}$ satisfies Foundation in addition, what axiom of $\mathsf{ZF}$ is missed?

Comment: @CameronBuie No! Shapiro in Ref. 1 is using higher order logic. Careful attention must be paied to how he defines $\phi^x$ the bounding is not merely $\in x$ but also $\subseteq x$, the first for set variables, the second for class variables. In addition he doesn't need supertransitivity because he already proved subclasses of sets to be sets from separation axiom, so this acts somehow to mask this issue, I'll write a posting about it and make sure if I got it right.

Comment: see here https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4318790/is-separation-subset-reflection-on-transitive-sets-strong-enough-to-go-beyond

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'll leave this open for now in case anyone can address R2.

Comment: @Zuhair, thank you for clarifying!

Comment: @Zuhair, I think that comment was intended for user76284.

Comment: @Zuhair I said "prove ZF - extensionality - foundation", not ZF itself. Are you sure the answer is no? Sorry if I misunderstood.

Comment: @user76284, Its my fault, Ive misunderstood your second question. OK, notice that $\phi^x$ used in R1 which is mentioned by  Ref 1 is not the same as $\phi^x$ used in R2 which is mentioned in Ref 2. If we define $\phi^x$ as how its defined in those references, then Yes ZF-Extensionality -Foundation would be provable in both. But if we take $\phi^x$ to be as you defined it, then only Ref2 manage to interpret ZF-Ext-Fnd.

Comment: Can your variant of R2 be simplified with the ideas expressed in the comments under [this answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/430883/74578)? (Note that, in the notation of that question, $\phi^u$ bounds only unbounded quantifiers to $u$.)

Comment: @user76284 I have no idea, and I do not think my variant of R2 is complex so it requires any simplification.