# Is separation + subset.reflection on transitive sets strong enough to go beyond ZF?

Tags: set-theory, reflection

This question is related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4028462/why-this-formulation-is-not-the-official-exposition-of-zf?noredirect=1#comment8999612_4028462) comment, and to this follow up [posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4318271/does-separation-reflection-prove-zf-extensionality-foundation).

Working in *mono-sorted* first order logic with equality and membership:

- *Define:* $set(x) \equiv_{df} \exists y \,  (x \in y)$
- Axiomatize:

1. **Extensionality:** $(\forall x \, (x \in a \leftrightarrow x \in b) \to a=b)$
2. **Separation:** $(set(a) \to \exists \ set \ x \, \forall y (y \in x \leftrightarrow y \in a \land \phi))$
3. **Reflection:** $\forall \ sets \ \vec{p} \ (\phi \to \exists \text { trs } x : set(x) \land \phi^x)$

Where $``\text { trs }"$ stands for transitive, to mean closure under membership $\in$ relation; and where formula $\phi$, only has $\vec{p}$ as its free variables, that doesn't use $``x"$ in both schemata; $\phi^x$ is the formula obtained from
$\phi$ by merely bounding all of its quantifiers by $``\subseteq x"$.

Now clearly this would prove all axioms of $\sf ZF-Reg$! I'm not sure if it is stronger than $\sf ZF$ and of the strength described in Page 6 of this [article](http://people.ucalgary.ca/%7Erzach/static/banff/rsl-specialissue/shapiro-uzquiano/shapiro-uzquiano.pdf), hence this question is about if that is the case?

Comment: How do you prove powerset from these axioms?

Comment: @MarkSaving, take $\phi$ to be the formula $\exists k (k = a \land \exists l (k \in l) \land \forall c ( c \subseteq k \to \exists h (c \in h))$; now take $a$ to be a set, now from reflection we get: $$\exists \text { trasitive set } x: \exists k \subseteq x  (k = a \land \exists l  \subseteq x (k \in l) \land \forall c  \subseteq x ( c \subseteq k \to \exists h \subseteq x (c \in h))$$; so there is a transitive set having all subsets of set $a$ among its elements, so from separation we get  the set $\mathcal P(a)$.

Comment: I see. Even simpler is $set(a) \land \forall y \subseteq a (set(y))$, since $set(b)^x$ is equivalent to $b \in x$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Call this new axiom system $K$.

First, note we can augment the reflection scheme to

$$ \exists x (trans(x) \land set(x) \land (\phi \iff \phi^x))$$

By simply doing case analysis on whether $\phi$ or $\neg \phi$ is true and applying the reflection principle in either case.

Now recall the class comprehension scheme of MK, which consists of all the axioms $A_\phi$ of the form

$$\forall \vec{P}\exists M (\forall x (set(x) \land \phi(\vec{P}, x) \iff x \in M))$$

For any formula $\phi(\vec{P}, x)$ (where $M$ does not appear). I claim each $A_\phi$ is provable from $K$.

For consider some transitive set $t$ such that $A_\phi$ is absolute for $t$. We wish to prove $A_\phi^t$. This formula becomes

$$\forall \vec{P} \subseteq t \exists M \subseteq t (\forall x \in t (\phi^t(\vec{P}, x) \iff x \in M))$$

Take some $\vec{P} \subseteq t$. Then such an $M$ exists by the separation axiom scheme. So we have proved the class comprehension scheme.

With the class comprehension scheme in hand, we can prove the consistency of ZF - Reg in a straightforward way. This is because we can develop the model theory of class-sized models and prove $V \models ZF - Reg$. We can then prove the soundness theorem for class-sized models to conclude that $ZF - Reg$ is consistent.

Comment: Wonderful! I was personally thinking along lines of proving the existence of a transitive set $t$ having the empty set among its elements and such that each iterative power of $\emptyset$ whose ordinal index is *accessible* [smaller than the first strongly inaccessible ordinal] then that iterative power is an element of that set, thereby proving $t$ to be strongly inaccessible set, and I think we can prove even stronger inaccessibles similarly. Thereby proving this theory to be way stronger than ZFC.

Comment: Since you've proved class comprehension schema, then I tend to think this theory is as strong as Bernay's theory spoken about in the linked Shapiro's article. I'm not sure if it is the same strength as Bernays reflection axiom mentioned in the wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_principle#As_new_axioms

Comment: How do you prove the augmented form of reflection in this theory?

Comment: @Zuhair If $\phi$, then take some transitive set $x$ such that $\phi^x$; then $\phi \iff \phi^x$. If $\neg \phi$, take some transitive set $x$ such that $(\neg \phi)^x$; then $\neg (\phi^x)$; then $\phi^x$ is false; then $\phi \iff \phi^x$. Also, your idea for proving the existence of inaccessibles appears to work.

Comment: I'm still not getting your argument of equivalence. If $\phi$ then take some transitive set $x$ such that $\phi^x$, this leads to $\phi \implies \phi^x$, I don't see how the equivalence is established?Similarily working for $\neg \phi$? You can say that  $\phi \implies \phi^x$ for some transitive set $x$, and also $\neg \phi \implies \neg \phi^y$ for some transitive set y, but I don't see why should $x=y$?

Comment: We seek to prove $\exists x (trans(x) \land set(x) \land (\phi \iff \phi^x))$. To do this, we split into two cases. Case 1: $\phi$. In this case, take some $x$ such that $trans(x) \land set(x) \land \phi^x$. Then since both $\phi$ and $\phi^x$ hold, so does $\phi \iff \phi^x$. Case 2: $\neg \phi$. Then take some $x$ such that $trans(x) \land set(x) \land (\neg \phi)^x$. Then $\neg (\phi^x)$. Then since both $\phi$ and $\phi^x$ are false, we have $\phi \iff \phi^x$.

Comment: I realized that the theory becomes inconsistent if we allow non set parameters in reflection. Would that affect your argument?

Comment: @Zuhair Ah, because of the statement $\exists x (x = M)$, where $M$ is a proper class, cannot be true when relativized. This makes sense. My argument still works with minimal modification, and I will update it when I have the chance.

Comment: @Zuhair To prove the existence of an inaccessible, note that we can strengthen the result to $V \models $ second-order $ZF - Reg$. From here, we can use reflection to get a small transitive model of second-order $ZF - Reg$. The smallest cardinal not in the model will be inaccessible.

Answer (score 0):

Let A0 be the set of axioms consisting of 1 and those in 2. Let A1 be the set of axioms in 1, those in 2, and those in the original 3(quantifiers not restricted to "sets"). Let A2 be the set of axioms consisting those in 1, 2 and 3. We will show that A1 is inconsistent and Con(A2) is provable in ZF.

(a)(A0)Suppose ∀(∈-->∈) and set(b).

Then set(a).

Proof: From 2, there is a set c with
x∈c<-->(x∈b∧x∈a).

(b) A1 is inconsistent.

Proof:Suppose that there is a b and ¬set(b).

Then ∃d(d=b).

By original 3, there is a transitve x such that ∃d(d⊆x∧d=b).

By (a), set(b). Therefore ∀b∃c(b∈c). By 3, there is a transitive x such that ∀b(b⊆x-->∃c(c⊆x∧b∈c). Therefore x∈x. By 2,  there is a d such that ∀y(y∈d↔y∈x∧y∉y). Since d⊆x, there is a c⊆x, such that d∈c.

Consequently d∈x andthus d∈d<-->d∉d.

(c) Con(A2) is provable in ZF.

Proof:Let F(f,n,x1,x2,...,xn) be a formula which says "f is a formula with n free variables holds" and there is an ordinal α such that "f(x1,x2,...,xn) holds in V(α+1)".

Let r be a limit ordinal which reflects F. That is for ∀f,n,x1,x2,...,xn∈Vr("F(f,n,x1,x2,...,xn) holds in Vr"<-->F(f,n,x1,x2,...,xn)).

1 holds in V(r+1). If " is a formula" holds and a,x1,x2,...xm∈V(r+1), then there is a x such that ∀(∈↔∈∧"(y,x1,x2,...,xm)
holds in V(r+1)").

Such an x must be in V(r+1). Therefore "2 holds in V(r+1)" holds.

To verify "3 holds in V(r+1)" holds, suppose x1,x2,...,xn∈Vr, "f is a formula with n free variables holds" and "f(x1,x2,...,xn) holds in V(r+1)".

Then F(f,n,x1,x2,...xn) holds. By reflection

"F(f,n,x1,x2,...,xn) holds in Vr".

That is there is a t∈r such that "f(x1,x2,...,xn) holds in V(t+1)".

Thus "3 holds in V(r+1)" holds. Since the statement "A2 holds in V(r+1)" holds, we have Con(A2).

Comment: But it appears that all axioms of ZF-Reg. are provable over the set realm of this theory, so how can this theory be proved consistent in ZF?

Comment: @Zuhair. Why do you think that replacement is provable?

Comment: @GregKiramyer, I see your point, when classes were allowed in parameters, then proving replacement is easy. However, I still think that replacement over the set realm would be provable. What is needed is that $\phi$ must be set bounded (all its quantifiers are bounded by the predicate $set$), and since all parameters are sets, then it appears to me that $\phi^x$ would preserve the truth values of $\phi$, in other words every set $y$ that satisfies $ set(a) \land \exists m \in a: \varphi(m,y)$ would also satisfy $ a \in x \land \exists m \in a : \varphi^x(m,y)$. I'll double check that.

Comment: @Zuhair, If you read my answer, I think you will agree with me that if ZF is consistent then replacement relativized to set() is not provable in A2.

Comment: I'll definitely read it. Howeve, the result is strange, since its known that in the first order language of set theory $ϕ→∃t:transitive(t)∧ϕ^t$ (where $\phi^t$ is relativization of quantifiers by $\in t$) together with Extensionality and Separation can prove Replacement. Now if we restrict parameters and quantiifers in $\phi$ to sets, then this would result in this reflection, so it must interpret Replacement over the set realm! I must be missing something?

Comment: @Zuhair. The sentence beginning "However", is not true. Try proving replacement or read my answer,

Comment: Kiramyer, see Kanamori on Bernays and set theory pages 20,21. https://www.researchgate.net/publication/220366286_Bernays_and_Set_Theory. The original proof is referenced in that article to be on: [12] , Zur Frage der Unendlichkeitsschemata in der axiomatischen Mengenlehre,
Essays on the foundations of mathematics (Bar-Hillel, Poznanski, Rabin, and Robinson,
editors), Magnes Press, Jerusalem, 1961, dedicated to Professor Abraham A. Fraenkel on
his 70th birthday, pp. 3–49